# Sieve of Eratosthenes Understanding

Tags: python, primes, sieve

I have this code I do not quite understand because I just started learning Python a week ago.

```
import numpy as np
import time

start_time=time.clock()

def Sieb(n):                           #Sieve
    Eins = np.ones(n, dtype=bool)      #Eins is just german for One
    Eins[0] = Eins[1] = False          #->I don't quite understand what
    for i in range(2, n):              #this one does.
        if Eins[i]:
            Eins[i*i::i] = False       #Does this make the ones = zero?
    return np.flatnonzero(Eins)


print Sieb(1000000)
print start_time
```

So, I understand the concept of the sieve (I guess) but I'm not sure how it is achieved here. 
Where are the multiples of itself get to `0` and how does the `np.flatnonzero` puts out the prime numbers because before that, they are just `1` and `0`?

I hope you can understand and help me. :)

Comment: `Eins[0] = Eins[1] = False`: because 0 and 1 are not primes.

Comment: `if Eins[i]: Eins[i*i::i] = False`: if a `i` number is False (= not a prime), set its square and every i-th following number to False/not a prime. That is the sieve part.

Comment: Note that the sieving part starts at the square, since every variant below that (2*i, 3*i, ...) has already been filtered out in a previous step (namely, for primes 2, 3, 5, ...).

Comment: Then looping from 2 to n, if Eins[i] is non-zero (i.e. a prime), we start from its square and set every ith element (i.e. its multiples) to False (i.e. Non-prime).

Comment: [`flatnontzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) is properly documented: it returns the (flattened) indices of non-zero (non-False, non-prime) numbers. Since we're using the indices as actual numbers to run the sieve on, that gives the primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Let's go through it step-by-step.

```
Eins = np.ones(n, dtype=bool)
```

This creates a new array of size *n*, with type `bool`, and all ones. Because of the type, "one" means `True`. The array represents all our numbers that we want to test for primality, with `True` meaning the number is prime, `False` meaning it is not. So we start with all numbers marked as (potential) primes.

```
Eins[0] = Eins[1] = False
```

Now we set the `0`th and `1`st element to `False`: Neither 0 nor 1 are primes.

```
for i in range(2, n):
```

Next, we'll iterate over all remaining numbers (from 2 onwards). We could get away with only going up to the square root of *n*, but for simplicity, we go over all numbers.

```
    if Eins[i]:
```

If the `i`th value of the array is `True`, that means `i` is a prime. The first time this condition will be entered is with `i=2`. Next, we want to remove all multiples of our number from the prime candidates:

```
        Eins[i*i::i] = False
```

We can read this line as if it was `Eins[2*i::i] = False`, starting from `i*i` is just an optimization¹. If 2 is a prime number, that means that 2*2, 3*2, 4*2, ... aren't, so we set the multiples to `False`. The indexing notation stands for "from `i*i` until the end" (represented by the empty space between the colons) ", in steps of `i`". This statement produces the numbers `i*i`, `i*(i+1)`, `i*(i+2)`, ..., so all multiples of `i` that haven't been marked as "not a prime" yet.

```
return np.flatnonzero(Eins)
```

And this simply returns all indices where the value is `True`, i.e. all prime numbers that were found.

---

1: A word regarding the `i*i`: We can start from the square of `i`, because any numbers `j*i` (for `j < i`) have already been marked as nonprime when we were at `j`.

---

#### Here's a demonstration that this works, for `n=15`:

We start with the array filled with `.ones`:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
[T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T]
```

Then we empty `Eins[0]` and `Eins[1]`:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
[F, F, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T]
```

And now we start iterating over the range, starting with `i=2`, and we remove every multiple of 2 starting with `2*2=4`:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
[F, F, T, T, F, T, F, T, F, T, F, T, F, T, F]
```

`i=3`, removing every multiple of 3 starting with `3*3=9`:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
[F, F, T, T, F, T, F, T, F, F, F, T, F, T, F]
```

Note that we didn't have to remove `6`, because it was already removed by `i=2`.

When `i=4`, we skip the removal because `Eins[i]` is `False`. From `i=5` onwards, nothing happens, because the squares (25, 36, ...) are larger than the array. Finally, we use `flatnonzero` and get all indices where the value is `True`:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
[F, F, T, T, F, T, F, T, F, F, F, T, F, T, F]
       2  3     5     7          11    13
```